# what will happen when we send a request to server

Tags: web-services, networking, web, network-protocols

my question is about, network request:

lets see an example:

I want to open a website(with domain name) that my browser doesn't have the destination ip.

what will happen to my request?

at network layer in tcp-ip, we must put an ip for our request. but we don't have the destination ip.

TNX...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need, given the domain name and needing the IP address, is a DNS lookup. DNS, or Domain Name Service, is the "phone book" of the internet, and consists of a hierarchical tree of servers, each one either knowing how to "map" or "resolve" a domain name to an IP address, or knowing which parent or child DNS server to route your request to, in order to get you closer to the server that does have this information.

It would be nice to know what language, runtime, OS and libraries you are using in your development. Using DNS is by no means a new problem, and therefore most languages and frameworks have a built-in way to do this. Even if you're rolling your own, the structure and protocol of DNS requests and their responses is extremely well-documented. But, any attempted answer as to exactly how you should do it in your case would be a shot in the dark given that we know nothing about your project other than that it uses TCP and needs an IP address.

Comment: you are right, I want to make a program(C#) like browser but not with full option. just sending a request and get feedback. when we have the ip then we can fill the request with ip, but when we don't have the ip what should we do? note: our request is about opening a web site not DNS request. Sorry that I can not get a better concept. weak in en

Comment: That's fine. However, my answer is still what you need to do; if you have a domain name, and you need an IP address to send the request, you need to perform a DNS lookup first, before making your request to the website. Other web browsers do exactly the same thing; when you type in "www.google.com", the browser asks your operating system to send a DNS request to the DNS server you specified when you set up your internet connection in the OS settings. The DNS server responds, hopefully with an IP address, which the browser then uses to send the HTTP Get request for the webpage.